# cmd / DOS / Batch command rename files as a Administrator

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dos, rename

i want to rename a file named somefile.exe to somefile2.exe in CMD or batch file(.bat)

when i do this in explorer i have to rename the file as a Admin. like this:

[image]

(sorry for swedish)

ok, i need to click "Continue" ("Fortsätt") and i can rename the file! very simple!

but in CMD.exe or batch file it says "Access Denied"
im using:

rename somefile.exe somefile2.exe

how can i do this in CMD or batch file? rename a file as a Admin?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click your command prompt shortcut and select ***Run as administrator***.

Then, run your batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the RunAs command.  You can run command as another user.
[see here - runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true)